# How can I get Activity Icon with Activity name

Tags: android, android-intent, icons

I have a problem to load Activity Icon with Activity name.

I have a pakcageName and a activity name, actually class name

I want to get Activity Icon

```
    'private List<ResolveInfo> apps;
    private PackageManager pm;

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    pm = getPackageManager();
    apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    ResolveInfo info = apps.get(position);

    pn =  info.activityInfo.packageName
    na = info.activityInfo.name

    imageView.setImageDrawable(pm.getActivityIcon(new ComponentName(pn, na)));'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public Drawable getActivityIcon(
        Context context, 
        String packageName, String activityName) {

    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, activityName));
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0);

    return resolveInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can find your application icon by this way:

1 - check in your manifest your application icon

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

2 - get it like that :

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```